# Set background color of text view based on whether it is the first responder

Tags: swift, textview

How can you set the background color of a text view based on whether it is the first responder?

It looks like a variation of this has been answered but it's in Objective C. I'm hoping there's a swift equivalent that constantly checks the state of the text view. Here's my code:

```
if messageInputBar.inputTextView.isFirstResponder {
         messageInputBar.inputTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
 } else {
         messageInputBar.inputTextView.backgroundColor = .white
 }
```

Comment: If you found a solution in Objective-C, you can use it in Swift. It's the same APIs. Just translate the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `textViewDidBeginEditing` and `textViewDidEndEditing` delegate methods. Update the text view's `backgroundColor` as desired.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.backgroundColor = .blue
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

And don't forget to set the `delegate` of each text view.